# Custom buttons on Highstock not enabled

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to display stock price for a stock in candlestick chart using highstocks. The data for the chart is from an external source http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=new-intraday.json

I created a number of buttons, but some of them are not being enabled even though data is there or seems to be there. To be precise, I can't get the 3min, 4 min buttons to be enabled when it seems the data is for every minute (I understand buttons for seconds and months won't work as data is for 9 days)

I have put it up here https://jsfiddle.net/amitabhr/e8ee8e02/4/

```
$(function () {
$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=new-intraday.json&callback=?', function (data) {

    // create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


        title: {
            text: 'AAPL stock price by minute'
        },

        rangeSelector : {
            buttons : [

            {
                type : 'second',
                count : 10,
                text : '10s'
            }, {
                type : 'second',
                count : 30,
                text : '30s'
            },

            {
                type : 'minute',
                count : 1,
                text : '1m'
            },
            {
                type : 'minute',
                count : 3,
                text : '3m'
            },
            {
                type : 'minute',
                count : 4,
                text : '4m'
            },
            {
                type : 'minute',
                count : 5,
                text : '5m'
            },
            {
                type : 'minute',
                count : 10,
                text : '10m'
            },
            {
                type : 'minute',
                count : 15,
                text : '15m'
            },
            {
                type : 'minute',
                count : 30,
                text : '30m'
            },

            {
                type : 'hour',
                count : 1,
                text : '1h'
            },
            {
                type : 'hour',
                count : 6,
                text : '6h'
            },{
                type : 'hour',
                count : 12,
                text : '12h'
            },

             {
                type : 'day',
                count : 1,
                text : '1D'
            },{
                type : 'day',
                count : 2,
                text : '2D'
            },{
                type: 'month',
                count: 1,
                text: '1m'
            }, 

            {
                type: 'month',
                count: 3,
                text: '3m'
            }, {
                type: 'ytd',
                text: 'YTD'
            }, {
                type: 'year',
                count: 1,
                text: '1y'
            }, {
                type : 'all',
                count : 1,
                text : 'All'
            }],
            selected : 1,
            inputEnabled : false
        },

        series : [{
            name : 'AAPL',
            type: 'candlestick',
            data : data,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

});

I checked the data source, below are the first and last three readings for the time (milliseconds converted to UTC)

Thu Oct 06 2011 08:00:00
Thu Oct 06 2011 08:01:00
Thu Oct 06 2011 08:02:00

Fri Oct 14 2011 15:57:00
Fri Oct 14 2011 15:58:00
Fri Oct 14 2011 15:59:00

As we can see the data is available for every minute, so I am not sure why I can't get the 2min, 3min buttons enabled.

Comment: You can set minrange and enable allbuttons by option. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/e8ee8e02/5/

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian Bochan. this was very helpful. If you could put this as answer, I could accept it as answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set minrange and enable allbuttons by option. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/e8ee8e02/5/

```
xAxis:{
            minRange: 10 * 60 * 1000
},
rangeSelector : {
            allButtonsEnabled:true
}
```